# .NET 3.5: Can Assembly.Load cause code execution in the loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, .net-assembly

I am working with .NET 3.5 , using `Assembly.Load`/`Assembly.LoadFrom` to load an externally compiled DLL at runtime, and then using reflection on the newly loaded types.

I am curious: is there any way for code in the loaded assembly to execute, strictly as a result of me loading it, not as a result of me constructing or invoking a method on one of its types?

I don't have any need to execute code automatically, I am simply curious what the limitations and potential side effects of loading assemblies are.

If it is possible, I'd love to see an example calling `Console.WriteLine` result of loading an assembly.

Comment: Yes, CLR support Module Initializers.